# Understanding AccessController.doPrivileged

Tags: java, security

I am going through this API, excerpt from javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/doprivileged.html#privileged_code

> "When the AccessController.checkPermission method is invoked by the
>   most recent caller, the basic algorithm for deciding whether to allow
>   or deny the requested access is as follows:
>
> 1. If the code for any caller in the call chain does not have the requested permission, then an AccessControlException is thrown
> 2. Unless the following is true: a caller whose code is granted the said permission has been marked as privileged, and all parties
>      subsequently called by this caller (directly or indirectly) have the
>      said permission."

As per my understanding from the above doc,

> Lets say frameA (having XYZ ) **->calls** frameB ( inherits the XYZ
>   permission) **->calls** frameC (inherits the permission XYZ). Because
>   the SecurityManager is common for the main thread
>
> So if the frameB wants to execute a code that needs permission ABC
>   then the policy should be  changed to grant that permission . But when
>   i  wrap the code in AccessController.doPrivileged it is not throwing
>   SecurtyException.
>
> So i am confused why it is behaving like this, is this because the
>   wrapped code  is automatically given "All Permission" ? If so, point2
>   above is contradicting this because it says **" a caller whose code is
>   granted the said permission has been marked as privileged"**

Following is what i am trying to test :

```
import java.security.*;

public class TestingDoPrivileged {

    static SecurityPermission XYZ = new SecurityPermission("xyz");
    static SecurityPermission ABC = new SecurityPermission("abc");
    static SecurityPermission SET_POLICY = new SecurityPermission("setPolicy");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setDummySecurityManager();
        frameA();
    }

    private static void frameA() {
        //set the permission XYZ
        setPolicy(XYZ,SET_POLICY);

        //Here the code/resource frameA  has access to XYZ permission
        //Now call frameB which needs ABC permission for the code to execute.
        frameB();

    }
    private static void frameB() {
        //this will pass as this code has the permission XYZ because the policy is set in frameA with XYZ permission
        System.getSecurityManager().checkPermission(XYZ);
        try {
            // this will fail as this code does not have permission for abc
            System.getSecurityManager().checkPermission(ABC);
        } catch (AccessControlException e) {
            System.out.println("passed");
            //pass
        }
        //As the caller of frameB which is frameA has the permission to XYZ only, the following code should fail,
        // right? But it is passing.
        AccessController.doPrivileged((PrivilegedAction) () -> {
            frameC();
            return null;
        });
    }
    private static void frameC() {
        System.getSecurityManager().checkPermission(ABC);
    }

    private static void setDummySecurityManager() {
        setPolicy(SET_POLICY);
        SecurityManager sm = new SecurityManager();
        System.setSecurityManager(sm);
    }
    private static void setPolicy(Permission... perms) {
        Policy.setPolicy(new Policy() {
            @Override
            public PermissionCollection getPermissions(CodeSource codesource) {
                PermissionCollection pc = new Permissions();
                for (Permission pm : perms)
                    pc.add(pm);
                return pc;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java 2 Security Model works on the **intersection** of the permissions of the relevant stack frames. If any relevant frame (or two-arg `doPrivileged`) doesn't have a permissions, then the access control context wont have that permission.

In the example it appears that the code is given just `XYZ` and `SET_POLICY`. Inside the `doPrivileged` call the calling frame (class `TestingDoPrivileged`) and the lambda frame wont have the `ABC` permission, so the check should fail.

What you might find happening with code like this, is that the permissions for the `CodeSource` is looked up only once. So code trying to change it's own permission may not behave as expected.

Running your code, it appears that `getPermissions` is never called. A look at the source of `Policy` reminds me that the `ProtectionDomain` of the `Policy` is given full permissions when set. It causes problems if the security implementation is not trusted (typically the stack overflows on recursive security checks).

It's better to use a policy file. That or play with class loaders.

Comment: So it this a bug in the Policy setting that is granting the ProtectionDomain all the permissions when the policy is set? 

So what happens if i were to use the policy file, finally the security impl should represent a Policy object which encompasses the permissions ?

Comment: @chebus The deliberate feature (necessary for some major applications servers to run the security manager enabled) is that the `ProtectionDomain`or the current `Policy` has all the permissions. If you were to use a policy file as usual, the `Policy` would be from the bootstrap class loader so the application class loader would create classes with `ProtectionDomain`s that were not fully trusted.

Comment: i am facing  an issue in that the code wrapped inside doPrivileged is working fine (means the permissions needed by the code wrapped are granted) in my local IDE as simple java application but the same is failing when run in jenkins as part of continous integration, 

as i am new to security api, i am slowly picking up pace on this method, however i am clueless where to start given my above problem

Comment: @chebus The `doPrivileged`code is working because the code has all permissions. Perhaps use `URLClassLoader` to load the `Policy` subclass in a different class loader.